# HLS stream cannot play on iPhone 6s and iPhone 7 but on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http-live-streaming, media-source

I have a live stream that plays well in browsers on computers, tablets, android and tested and working in **iOS on iPhone 4S**.

The iPhone 4S uses the **latest update**. However, when I try it on **iPhone 6s or 7** it doesn't play for some reason.

What could be the reason for this **breaking behaviour** in newer iOS devices?

Comment: What's the reason? Do you get an error message on the newer devices?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to such a phone, but when testing from a friends it doesn't work. I usually have it in production mode so I am unable to see any error messages which I normally log to the server. It's a bit of a problem not being able to test it properly. On 4S as stated it works. I need to get my hands on a 6 or 7 but I think it's strange since it relies on MediaSource and not hls.js.